# Sometimes "duplicate children added" error, sometimes not

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I'm using JavaFX 8 to try to create Panes that runs on a separate threads and are on the same Stage/window. This is the logic of my code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

VBox vbxMain;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    vbxMain = new VBox(10d);

    addLabel(new HBox(new Label("LABEL")));
    new Thread(new Threader(this)).start();
    new Thread(new Threader(this)).start();

    stage.setScene(new Scene(vbxMain, 100, 100));
    stage.show();
}   

public void addLabel(Pane node) {
    vbxMain.getChildren().add(node);
}
```

}

```
public class Threader implements Runnable {

Main main;

public Threader(Main main) {
    this.main = main;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Label lblText = new Label("Hello");
    HBox hbxMain = new HBox(lblText);
    main.addLabel(hbxMain);
}
```

When I run this, sometimes it displays:

```
LABEL
Hello
Hello
```

With no error, but other times it'll display only one Hello or no Hellos.
The error is:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = VBox@36269e7b
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at test3.Main.addLabel(Main.java:32)
    at test3.Threader.run(Threader.java:18)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = VBox@36269e7b
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at test3.Main.addLabel(Main.java:32)
    at test3.Threader.run(Threader.java:18)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Note that in my actual code, what would be providing "Label lblText" is another class which I initialize then call a method to retrieve a VBox.

So why does the error only occur sometimes, how do I fix this and is there a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manipulate any parts of the GUI with Platform.runLater() if you need to do it from any other than the application (Main) thread.